# How to write two different rules in one .htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to write these two different rules in one file. How I have to do it?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /v0\.3/forum/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /v0.3/test.php?forum=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /v0\.3/profile/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /v0.3/profiles.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: remove second `RewriteEngine On` it should be working, and if you have some debug messages, show us

Comment: thanks, done. with edited .htaccess content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply delete the second `RewriteEngine On` declaration

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /v0\.3/forum/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /v0.3/test.php?forum=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /v0\.3/profile/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /v0.3/profiles.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```